# putty won't close after starting script with -m option

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal, putty

with this script

```
putty -ssh user@host -i C:\Users\TheUser\.ssh\id_rsa.ppk -m C:\users\TheUser\desktop\script.txt

exit
```

I tried to automate a network shutdown after a backup on the Remote NAS, synology, running on linux.

`skript.txt` looks like the following `sh /home/linuxserver/Dokumente/shell.sh & disown; exit` and the skript on the linuxserver looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10s

sudo ip link set eth0 down
```

my problem is that the script does what it is made for but the putty Terminal is not closed. If I copy the content of `script.txt` in a putty terminal myself and execute it it works as intended (with closing the terminal).

edit: it looks like putty ignores every command to disown a script. even if I create a script to disown a script. `nohup`, `& disown`, and `& disown -h` does not work. I even tried to start putty create a session and save it, but these commands where generally ignored.

edit2: now i tried it with another command in skript.txt it looks now like

```
(sleep 10; sudo ip link set eth0 down ) &

exit
```

the Putty still don't close after I start the script, so I tried another skript.txt

```
(sleep 10; echo 1000 ) &

exit
```

I changed the sleep time and every time putty waited till the time is over. so my question is how can I start my script and let it close the putty window without manually closing the window?